# Select order of bean injection for multiple candidates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

In my program I have 3 beans that all implements the same interface and apply some configurations depending on some environment variables present where the application is deployed.

Bean `A` is always available and beans `B` and `C` are only built if a `@ConditionalOnProperty` is present.

In some places I need to inject `B`, in others `C`, and use `A` as a fallback if either is not present:

```
@Autowired
public MyService(SomeCommonInterface somebean)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do would be to dynamically create the bean you want based on the properties you have. This will allow you to add your own logic for creating the appropriate bean.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = BeansOrder.BeansOrderConfig.class, properties = {
        "my_custom_property_C: true"
})
public class BeansOrder {
    @Configuration
    static class BeansOrderConfig {
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public SomeCommonInterface bean() {
            if (env.containsProperty("my_custom_property_B")) {
                return new ImplB();
            }
            if (env.containsProperty("my_custom_property_C")) {
                return new ImplC();
            }
            return new ImplA();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    SomeCommonInterface bean;

    @Test
    void tst() {
        System.out.println(bean.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

If it grows larger, you can extract it into a separate class that will return the appropriate implementation based on some parameters, basically the `factory` design pattern